# How to make a search filter in flutter

Tags: flutter

So I'm using an API for the search filter which means that all the logic of the search filter is in the API, My job is to call the search filter API. I have tried to call the search API in the textfield on the onChange event. But the search API won't recognize any single alphabets on the textcontroller. The Search perfectly works, I have tested it, but it didn't work when I display the list.

```
TextField(
          
             controller:searchQuery,
               onChanged:(string)
            {
                  setState(() {
                _provider.getSearch(searchQuery.toString());
              });
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
            hintText: ''
           ),
          ),
         )
```

It's empty when I tried to search
[image: It's empty when I tried to search]

It actually reads the input that I type when I debug,
[image: It actually reads the input that I type, when I debug,]

When I manually input the parameter it display all the list

```
Container(
           margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10,horizontal: 10),
           child:TextField(
          
             controller:searchQuery,
               onChanged:(string)
            {
                  setState(() {
                _provider.getSearch("r");
              });
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
            hintText: ''
           ),
          ),
         )
```

[image]

Comment: searchQuery.toString() to searchQuery.text or use string variable of onChanged method, it should work fine.

Comment: @Ninja bruh u are the best !

Comment: @Ninja Can you write your comment as an answer, so that OP can mark it as a correct answer, and it might help someone else in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`searchQuery.toString()` to `searchQuery.text` or use string variable of onChanged method.